# Safari 9.1 update breaks iframes caching

Tags: asp.net, iframe, safari

I have an issue that Safari is caching my iFrames.
The following (pseudo) HTML (well, it is an aspx page) is OK in Safari 9.0 and all other browsers on Mac and PC.

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="page1" src="Page1.aspx" />
<iframe id="page2" src="Page2.aspx" />
</body>
</html>
```

in Safari version 9.1, even though

1. Caching is entirely turned off in the developer toolbar
2. I hit Mac+R to reload the page

It will send a call to the server to fetch Page1 or Page2 but instead of showing that it will present an old version of that page. No Javascript errors or similar from what I can see.

I know that I could add a randomized number or something similar, however, this only helps partly, since a postback inside the iframe, again, will present the cached page.

Any others out there that have found a workaround? I also set all the prama no cache etc. to avoid this, no luck.

I have tried this also in El Capitan with the same result so it looks like to be connected to Safari 9.1 update (10601.5.17.4)

I also traced the traffic on the server and the request is actually happening and the correct html is returned back to the client, this is however not visible in the "Network" section in the Safari network trace. ASP.Net v.4.0.

MacBook Air, OS X Yosemite (10.10.5), Safari version 9.1 (10601.5.17.4)

Comment: Ok I found it at last after hours of testing....    contentWindow.location.reload(true) does not do what it should.. also the old iframe.src = iframe.src which usually reloads the iframe did not do anything... so adding a unique number to the URL in the part where the iframe should have been reloaded, plus adding unique number to the initial iframe src, sorted out this. I got tricked by fiddler output.

Comment: Yep, same problem here.

Comment: Issue was fixed with the follow up version to Safari 9.1 - all working as expected now.

Answer (score 2):

We are observing the same issue with our application. We render some content in an iframe that is changed by controls found in the outer page. As of Safari 9.1, the iframe does not render the changes even though it does fetch the updated content from the server.

Using the context menu to display the iframe in a new tab shows the updated content without re-fetching, so it is clearly within Safari's memory but just not rendered to the screen in iframe context.

It appears right now that the only solution is to start using cache-busing URLs like the bad old days... Safari really should honor the cache control header in this case.